# Will this bounce work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Here is my problem:
I made a really awesome Animar EDH deck and one of my infinite combos involves [Animar, Soul of elements](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Animar%2C%20Soul%20of%20elements) with 4 +1/+1 counters on it. This will allow me to summon [Pierce Strider](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pierce%20Strider) for free. I would then use [Cloudstone Curio](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudstone%20Curio)'s ability in order to bounce back pierce strider back into my hand and virtually allow me to cause 4 points of damage to my opponent infinitely!
Can this combo actually **WORK**!? It says on cloudstone curio that

> "Whenever a **nonartifact** permanent enters the battlefield under
> your control, you may return another permanent you control that shares
> a permanent type with it to its owner's hand"

and pierce strider is an artifact but is also a creature. So will this work?

Comment: Note that instead of Pierce Strider, you can just use any creature that deals damage when it enters the battlefield (like Blisterstick Shaman). You will just need a second creature (any non-artifact creature) to bounce and recast because the creature that deals damage can't bounce itself.

Comment: Oops, I missed that only colorless mana is reduced. So you would need a creature that only costs colorless mana, which won't work for non-artifacts.

Comment: @GendoIkari Oh there are [some non-artifact creatures who would disagree,](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&subtype=+[Eldrazi]&color=+[C]&type=+[Creature]) if they had minds that we could fathom.

Comment: @Gendolkari Would [Rattleclaw Mystic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386634) work? Morphs only cost colorless mana. So you cast Rattleclaw for free, flip it, bounce it, and repeat for infinite mana (I think). I can't find any morphs that do damage when they flip, but infinite mana seems like the next best thing.

Comment: Also, [Horde Ambusher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386559) works. Cast it for free, reveal a red card to flip it, bounce it, and repeat. Animar becomes arbitrarily large can't be blocked (unless an opposing creature has hexproof, shroud, protection from red, etc.).

Comment: @ghoppe None of those deal damage when they enter the battlefield. But Rainboltnfiund examples that work.

Comment: @Lohoris Rattleclaw give {R}{U}{G} when it flips and only costs {2} so it will give infinite mana in those 3 colors

Comment: @diego I misread {R}, {U} or {G} :v

Comment: @Rainbolt I like that idea, but remember you have to return *another* permanent to your hand, so you'll need two. Another card to add to this deck to enable the infinite combo could be a [Burning-Tree Emissary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366467)! They both could work together, or alone as multiples. — I guess with EDH they'll be alone so we'll need to find more cards like this. ;-)

Comment: @ghoppe I kept digging around and found [Kobolds of Kher Keep](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=kobolds+of+kher+keep), [Crimson Kobolds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=1565), and [Crookshank Kobolds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=159770). All three are free and can be bounced by Curio, similar to Burning-Tree but without the initial investment. They can be tutored for free with something like Chord of Calling or [Citanul Flute](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=135244).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your combo will not work for two reasons.

**Cloudstone Curio never triggers.**

[Cloudstone Curio](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudstone%20Curio) triggers when a nonartifact permanent enters the battlefield. [Pierce Strider](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pierce%20Strider) is an artifact, and so it will not cause Cloudstone Curio to trigger.

**You must choose another permanent.**

Cloudstone Curio says you may return another permanent. "Another" in this case means "not the thing that caused the trigger".

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 reasons it doesn't work. One, even though it is a creatures, it is also an artifact, so it fails the **nonartifact** clause. Second, Curio also says "another permanent", meaning you can't bounce the permanent that just entered the battlefield.